# Need Help getting the unique values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to get the unique values using query function in google sheets

| Col1 | Col1 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12 | 111 |
| A | 2 | 13 | 222 |
| A | 2 | 14 | 333 |
| B | 3 | 15 | 444 |
| B | 3 | 16 | 555 |
| B | 4 | 17 | 666 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWgF9.png)

I would like to get the output like below

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
A     1   12    111
A     2   13    222
          14    333
B     3   15    444
          16    555
      4   17    666
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qIBn.png)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A&B1:B, A1:A&B1:B, 
 ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A))=1, A1:B, ), C1:D})
```

[image]